# ROS Rviz Error: “Could not connect to any X display”

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling since days to install ROS & Rviz on my Windows 10 Pc. I first installed Ubuntu melodic using windows app store and followed the tutorial from ROS Wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).
So, I tried to start rviz using:

```
roscore &
rosrun rviz rviz
```

Then it says:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.

Using

```
sudo visudo
```

I added these 2 lines to sudoers.tmp

```
Defaults env_keep+="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
Defaults env_keep+="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
```

However the same error occurs. What else could I try?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335787/ros-rviz-error:-%E2%80%9Ccould-not-connect-to-any-x-display%E2%80%9D/) by [xman236](https://answers.ros.org/users/47615/xman236/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am struggling since days to install ROS & Rviz on my Windows 10 Pc. I first installed Ubuntu melodic using windows app store

This implies that you're using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) to run an Ubuntu user land and have installed ROS into that.

Windows 10 nor WSL come with an X Server, which is the part that renders the graphical windows required to use the UI part of ROS (ie: RViz, Gazebo, etc). You don't appear to have an X Server running (and probably neither have one installed), but still try to run `rviz`, you receive the error message ("Could not connect to any X display").

You'll have to install a suitable X Server on the Windows 10 side (so *not* inside WSL). See [this AskUbuntu Q&A for some more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225). In the past people have used VcXsrv and Xming. Whether those still work I couldn't say.

And finally: you may already be aware, but although WSL (and WSL 2) are very nice and convenient from a technological perspective, there are still certain things that don't work correctly with it. At least with WSL 1 (ie: the original one) networking has always been a weak point, and seeing as ROS is extensively networked, certain aspects of ROS were not as robust running under WSL as they could be. See #q238646 for an earlier question.

This situation could have improved and WSL 2 uses a rather different approach to how WSL is implemented and run, but I wanted to let you know as you may run into problems that could, potentially, be caused by WSL and not ROS or its configuration.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-21**:
Previous Q&As about this: #q326692, #q278427, #q315056,